# How to simulate U2F/MFA devices

Tags: authentication, web-applications, browser, multi-factor-authentication

Is there any solution how to simulate devices for U2F/MFA for development web apps? I use Windows 10 operating system, but i prefer OS independently solution.

Comment: You want something that simulates U2F/MFA so you can test the workflow when you are developing web apps? Why not just use U2F/MFA?

Comment: You can use Apps like Google Authenticator. It generates you this codes on your phone

Comment: This is not answer for that question. I am looking for software that can simulate physical hw token for 2FA on local computer, not third party web API. I found some github project like https://github.com/danstiner/rust-u2f but this is only for Linux.